# how to change a page without logout a user in Javascript and firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, href

I'm a beginner in firebase with javascript but I would like to develop a web app using firebase to get my authentification part. (Because the app is also connect with an iPhone/Ipad App)

For now I've got my connection page with two field, one for the email and the second one for the password. When I click on Connect Button I use the firebase function for the authentification and I request from javascript to open the second web page.

But my question is how can I get keep the user ID from firebase in my new web page ?

Also How can I check if the user is logged on the website and he is not here without permission ?

my login code :

```
function login() {
  var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;

  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass)
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;

      window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);

      document.location.reload(false);
    });

  window.alert("Welcome");
  $("#connection").hide();
  UserExist();
}

function logout() {
  firebase.auth().signOut();
}

function UserExist() {
  document.location.href = "desktop.html";
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: use cookie or localStorage to store token be make it persistent and you can check it in any page as long as you are on the same domain.

Comment: I've check how to use cookies, my code is : `var ref = new Firebase("https://XXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com");
   var authData = ref.getAuth();
   document.cookie = "UserID="+authData.uid+"; expires=; path=/"` this code is just added before calling the function `UserExist()` but the code didn't work ...

Comment: use this package to manage cookie https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie, it is more easier.

Comment: My cookie is working but the way to get my UserId during the connection didn't work ...

Comment: how do you open second web page

Comment: with this code `document.location.href="desktop.php";`

Comment: how do you open your code? file:///C:/.../desktop.html or of http:// localhost/desktop.html ?

Comment: Know it work ! I'll publish soon the new code to get my UserID !

Answer (score 0):

you have to use refresh token and save the token in your local-storage